# Configure Empathy with Office Communicator 2007

Tags: 11.10, empathy, pidgin

I am using Pidgin with Sipe to connect with Office Communicator 2007.

Is it is possible with Empathy?

I had imported from Pidgin but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the pidgin-sipe plugin for Empathy as well.

1. Just select the **sipe** Protocol from the list in Empathy when adding account.
2. Enter your OCS **email** and **password** and **log in**.

Worked that simply for me.

Comment: Had u tried,because i have tried this but not working

Comment: Yes, but I did not import anything from Pidgin though. Just created a new sipe account in Empathy, entered my company email and it worked. Still get some connection errors now and again though, but most of the time it just works.

Comment: If this worked for you I'd be grateful if you could mark my answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me (Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.10).

Step 1: install pidgin-sipe plugin (you can do this via Terminal or Ubuntu Software Center)

Step 2: RESTART THE COMPUTER. Common error is because users don't restart the computer after installing pidgin-sipe (SIPE will not show up on the list of accounts that you can configure with Empathy if you did not restart).

Step 3: Once the computer has restarted, open Empathy and add your account (you should see SIPE in the list from this point)

Step 4: Enter your credentials

a. In the "Account" field, type your company email address.
b. In the "Login" field, enter your credentials (typically it's domain\username)
c. Left everything else untouched, and then clicked on Apply (or Login).

Note, some organizations may require that you import some certificate files/keys. In my organization it did not that's why it worked.

Comment: Did someone try it with 12.10? I can't SIPE on the list of protocols.

Comment: Do you know any way to import those certificates? In Pidgin it opens a pop up window, and it asks me to accept, i do, and it works. In Empathy this doesn't happen so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works with version 1.9 of the plugin. With version 1.11 I got a lot of 'read error's.

Comment: Saw read errors can be fixed on this post: http://blogs.kent.ac.uk/iancarter/2010/06/24/connecting-to-office-communicator-ocs-using-empathy/